# .reg file to run bash script with parameter that contains whitepsace

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm making a .reg file to run a bash script with first input parameter as the selected file/folder path in context menu. However, if the file/folder path contains whitespace, the first parameter got sent only the part before the space. Everything else is sub sequence parameters. For example

```
C:\Folder1\Folder With Space
```

will be sent as

```
C:\Folder1\Folder
```

to the `script.sh`

This is my .reg file content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Run with Script]
"Icon"="D:\\path\\to\\icons.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Run with Script\command]
@="bash.exe -c \"/bin/bash /mnt/d/somepath/to/script.sh $(/bin/wslpath -u \"%1\")\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Run with Script]
"Icon"="D:\\path\\to\\icons.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Run with Script\command]
@="bash.exe -c \"/bin/bash /mnt/d/somepath/to/script.sh $(/bin/wslpath -u \"%1\")\""
```

`$(/bin/wslpath -u \"%1\")` is the part where Windows path will be convert to unix based path. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you already have the path, try `"%~n1"`

Comment: did you try `$(/bin/wslpath -u '%1')`

Comment: that solved it, thanks!